# Cannot format SD Card

Tags: android, windows, raspberry-pi, sd-card

I wanted to format my micro sd card so I could use it with my Raspbian pi zero. When I tried to format it with cmd using chkdsk, it said the format of the sd card is raw. diskpart could not format the card either. 
I've tried formatting it through Windows disk management as well, but to no avail. 
The sd card works fine in an Android phone, and I was able to format it on the phone as well, but it still is inaccessible through my PC.

Any tips on how to properly format it would be appreciated.

Comment: hi ekiwaka, welcome to stackoverflow - a programming QA community. given your question is more related to general computer stuff, i would suggest you to visit [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/). that being said, i personally suspect something is wrong with your microsd card reader.

Comment: @BagusTesa but it works well with my phone. should I just give up on trying to format it and order a new one?

Comment: how did you format it anyway..?